# Is it possible that the comments from a NodeJS script create memory issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, comments, ram

I write NodeJS libraries and I usually put JSDoc comments in the code, generating documentation then.

So, my code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Sum
 * Calculates the sum of two numbers.
 *
 * @name Sum
 * @function
 * @param {Number} a The first number,
 * @param {Number} b The second number.
 * @return {Number} The sum of the two numbers.
 */
module.exports = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

When this script will be required from another NodeJS script, will the comment above be loaded in the RAM?

So, do the big comments affect the memory somehow?

I guess the NodeJS scripts are parsed and irrelevant things (e.g. comments) are not kept in the memory. Is this true?

So, in conclusion, can such comments create any memory issues?

---

### Examples

Stringifying a function, the comment is printed too:

```
function foo () {
    // Hello World comment
    return 10;
}

console.log(foo.toString());
```

Output:

```
$ node index.js 
function foo() {
    // Hello World comment
    return 10;
}
```

---

Another example is to generate `lorem ipsum` on 2 million lines and then, on the last line `console.log(1)`.

So, the file looks like:

```
 // long lorem ipsum on each line
 // ...
 // after 2 million lines
 console.log(1)
```

Running the script above I get:

```
$ node run.js 
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This happened on a 16GB RAM machine.

---

I also compared the performance of a simple console.log(1) file with one that has lot of comments:

```
$ time node with-comments.js
1

real    0m0.178s
user    0m0.159s
sys 0m0.023s

$ time node no-comments.js
1

real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: Who do you think it may be loaded into memory? Usually comments are ignored by the precompiler/interpreter.

Comment: @whirlwin See the edit. Stringifying a function keeps the comment there. So, it means the comment is in memory, right?

Comment: the whole source code is kept in memory for "stringify" purpose, which may, in fact, influence the code performance while the code is parsed and interpreted, but this does **NOT** affect runtime performance, or at least should not.

Comment: @micnic *the whole source code is kept in memory* -- then that's weird... Is there any way to disable this *feature*?

Comment: @IonicăBizău, no, this is a "standard" feature of the language (it is present in browsers too), using a minifier will solve this.

Comment: @micnic Well, what if I modify and recompile Node on my machine? :-) It's not a critical issue, but it could be I guess... BTW, what's the reference for the thing that the whole source is kept in memory?

Comment: @IonicăBizău, well, you should modify and recompile V8 :) I am not sure about the whole source code, but for functions I'm sure, and as @FlorianMargaine said in his answer (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2), `Function.prototype.toString` return the function declaration (as it is in the source code), and node modules are just files consisting of one big function so node modules source code is kept in memory.

Comment: it's a script language, it has to load the script into memory to know what to do with it.  If it's a 10mb script file, it'll load it into memory even if 99.999% of it is comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your `.toString()` code prooves, all comments are kept in memory as a part of the function source code, which in node modules outside a function is the module function. You can strip comments out in your build step.

V8 keeps the source in memory because it is the most compact representation of the function, the AST and other intermediate representations are created on the fly as needed and then thrown away.

Comment: *You can strip comments out in your build step.* -- the *build step* is  before releasing a new module version?

Comment: @IonicăBizău yes, you have a build step right? You don't write raw js by hand?

Comment: @Esailija for node code, there's no reason to not write raw js by hand.

Comment: @Esailija I do write the code by hand, without using any language like coffescript etc... But I will see how can I improve that. Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău The build step doesn't need to involve any other languages. It's the stage where you run your tests, lint, minifier, and other such tools (typically using a tool like grunt). It's very important to have a reproducible, reliable build (if someone else wants to build your code, or you set up CI).